# How to run already complete Ruby on Rails application in Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

My friend emailed me a sample application that contains the folders "app, bin, config db lib log public test tmp vendor" and the files "gitignore, config.ru, gemfile, gemfile.lock, rakefile, readme.rdoc"

I've configured RoR on my computer and got hello world working. But how do I begin to run his sample program? I'm very confused on what step to take from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure you have `bundler` installed:

`gem install bundler`

2. `cd` to your application directory

`cd path\to\application`

3. Run `bundle install` - this would install all the dependencies that are required to run the rails application.
4. Ensure that you have the database installed/configured. Check `config\database.yml` for `development` settings.
5. Run `rake db:create db:migrate db:seed` - this would create your database schema, add seed data.
6. Finally, run `rails server`.

Answer (score 1):

If ruby is installed and working, run cmd.exe and go to your friend's app directory

```
cd myfriendsApp
```

all you have to do is type the command

```
"rails server" (without quotes)
```

and look the result in your browser at http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 1):

In the command line, navigate into the folder you got from your friend.  Do the following:

```
rake db:create # to create the database
rake db:migrate # to do the migrations to build the schema of the db
rails s #start a server
```

That should have all run without errors.  If that is the case then go to `http://localhost:3000` in the browser.